# How can I UPDATE multiple rows with JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:
importer:
[image: IMPORTER]

categories:
[image: CATEGORIES]

product_categories:
[image: PRODUCT_CATEGORIES]

How can I set "categories.name" to "importer.tag" when "importer.sku" = "product_categories.product_reference"?

Comment: Add more description so that others can understand your requirement

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Im using MySql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
UPDATE categories
SET name = importer.tag
FROM
    categories
    INNER JOIN product_categories ON categories.id = product_categories.category_id
    INNER JOIN importer ON importer.sku = product_categories.product_reference;
```

Note that this will update all possible records in the categories table (where joins with product_categories and importer tables are possible). If you need to update only specific records in categories, also use a WHERE clause.

Edit:

Not categories.name should be updated, but importer.tag... Sorry...

```
UPDATE importer
SET tag = categories.name
FROM
    importer
    INNER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.product_reference = importer.sku
    INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = product_categories.category_id;
```

Edit 2:

As a MS SQL Server user, I was not aware that MySQL uses a slightly different syntax for UPDATE queries. After a quick glance at the MySQL documentation, you may try the following query instead:

```
UPDATE
    importer
    INNER JOIN product_categories ON product_categories.product_reference = importer.sku
    INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = product_categories.category_id
SET
    tag = categories.name;
```

Comment: But by this way i am updating "categories" and not "importer" as I want, true?

Comment: Ah. You want to update importer table. That's the other way around. I misread your question. I will update my answer.

Comment: Just updated my answer. The original FROM-clause would do too, but I prefer to start with the main/target table for clarity/readability.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Wrong sintax near to "from". Why can it be?

Comment: Hmmm. That depends. Perhaps your database system does not support FROM in UPDATE queries. What database system do you use?

Comment: Ah. I see it in the title of your post now. Sorry. Seems that MySQL uses a slightly different UPDATE syntax than SQL Server. I will edit my answer again.

Comment: Now that code dont fail, but my phpMyAdmin stays loading. Thanks man for your time.

Comment: You're very welcome. :) If the answer is OK for you, can you mark it as such, please?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE imp 
  SET imp.tag= cat.name
  FROM categories cat 
  Inner join product_categories pc ON pc.categoryId = cat.categoryId
  INNER JOIN importer imp ON imp.product_reference = pc.product_Reference
```

Comment: Sorry, but i want update "importer" and not "categories"